# Matrix Multiplication in 3,4 axes pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

I've two tensors of shape `a(16,8,8,64)` and `b(64,64)`. Suppose, I extract last dimension of `a`into another column vector `c`, I want to compute `matmul(matmul(c.T, b), c)`. I want this to be done in each of the first 3 dimensions of `a`. That is the final product should be of shape `(16,8,8,1)`. How can I achieve this in pytorch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done as follows:

```
row_vec = a[:, :, :, None, :].float()
col_vec = a[:, :, :, :, None].float()
b = (b[None, None, None, :, :]).float()
prod = torch.matmul(torch.matmul(row_vec, b), col_vec)
```